# Automatic Logout in ASP.NET using JS showing Error

Tags: javascript, c#

I have tried to logout from a session by calling a C# action but it shows an error logout not found

take a look at it,

Controller Action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    Session.Clear();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I have used a simple Javascript to automate this after 5 seconds
JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Home", FormMethod.Post)';
        }, 5000);
    </script>
```

But the compiler is showing this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPZBJ.png)

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/Logout
```

Comment: That's not a compiler error. That's a runtime error. You might want to review the differences between those.

Comment: What URL ends up being placed in the JavaScript? Does that match the expected URL? Have you tried using a GET instead of a POST?

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` will perform a GET, not a POST, and your server is only providing a POST endpoint.